# Не отрисовывается объект при работе в pygames

Tags: python, pygame

Учусь писать с использованием `pygame`, ниже код, который должен вывести спрайт корабля, однако программа выводит закрашенное окно без корабля.

**game.py**

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_lengh, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    ship = Ship(screen)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

**ship.py**

```
import pygame
class Ship():
    def __init__(self,screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**settings.py**

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_lengh = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (10,30,40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все работает правильно.
Проверьте изображение и путь к нему.
Экран у меня меньше чем у вас, обратите на это внимание.

```
import sys
import pygame


#from settings import Settings
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_lengh = 1200
        self.screen_height = 600                                   # 800
        self.bg_color = (10, 30, 40)
                

#from ship import Ship
class Ship():
    def __init__(self,screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")         
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        print(f'self.rect 1      -> {self.rect}')                  # +
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        print(f'self.screen_rect -> {self.screen_rect}')           # +
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        print(f'self.rect 2      -> {self.rect}')                  # +
    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_lengh, ai_settings.screen_height))
    print(f'\nscreen           -> {screen}')                       # + 
    
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    ship = Ship(screen)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()
        
run_game()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ship.bmp**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]